# Visual Studio 2013 Database Projects: Difference between unresolved reference error SQL71561 and warning SQL71562

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, database-project

I've got two seemingly similar SQL Server Database Projects in two Visual Studio 2013 solutions which give very different results when I build them.  One builds fine, with multiple warnings but no errors.  The other fails to build with multiple errors.

The thing I find strange is the warnings in the project that builds and the errors in the project that doesn't seem to be the same, apart from the error numbers.  Both have almost identical messages.

eg Error:

```
SQL71561: View: [dbo].[vw_missed_sla] has an unresolved reference 
to object [Database2].[dbo].[order_line].
```

eg Warning:

```
SQL71562: Trigger: [dbo].[trg_UserStatusType_CHANGE] has an unresolved reference 
to object [Database3].[dbo].[ReferenceTable].
```

My question is: Why in one project do the unresolved references generate only warning SQL71562 messages but in the other project they generate error SQL71561 messages?  What is the difference between a SQL71561 error and a SQL71562 warning?

As far as I can see the database properties of each project are identical.  I've been through each of the tabs in the two Project Properties screens side by side.  Both are targeting SQL Server 2005 databases.

Comment: Maybe MS decided that an unresolved reference in a View was more important than an unresolved reference in a Trigger?

Comment: I think it has to do with whether or not you can create the object as is in the database. You couldn't create the view without the underlying table, but triggers, like procs, can be created if the object is in another DB. Adding DB references should help resolve this.

Comment: @Peter Schott: Thanks, that makes sense.  Adding a DB reference fixed the errors.

Comment: I have observed the same behavior. Views generate errors but stored procedures and functions generate warnings.